# how to avoid the millisecond part from localtimestamp?

Tags: sql, oracle

select localtimestamp from dual;

The above query shows the result as 22-FEB-12 04.27.02.225354000 PM this format.

How to write the query to get 22-FEB-12 04.27.02 PM

Comment: That's just a string representation of the actual data. Whenever you show it to a user you're likely applying formatting anyway. So why bother at the database level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either:

```
select current_date from dual;
```

Or:

```
select to_char(localtimestamp,'dd-MON-yyyy hh.mi.ss AM') from dual;
```

Though neither return a `timestamp` format.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(dateColumn, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH12.MI.SS PM')
```

Check the documentation for more information on the TO_CHAR function, as well as supported formats:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions180.htm#i1009324

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm

Answer (score 0):

If the result must be a TIMESTAMP there are several options.  Try running the following:

```
SELECT LOCALTIMESTAMP,
       CAST(LOCALTIMESTAMP AS TIMESTAMP(0)) AS CAST_TIMESTAMP0,
       CURRENT_DATE,
       CAST(CURRENT_DATE AS TIMESTAMP) AS DATE_CAST_TO_TIMESTAMP,
       TO_TIMESTAMP(TO_CHAR(LOCALTIMESTAMP, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AS CHAR_TIMESTAMP,
       CAST(TO_TIMESTAMP(TO_CHAR(LOCALTIMESTAMP, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AS TIMESTAMP(0)) AS TRUCATED_TIMESTAMP
  FROM DUAL
```

Note that the CAST_TIMESTAMP0, CURRENT_DATE, and DATE_CAST_TO_TIMESTAMP values are rounded to the nearest second rather than truncated - re-run the query until the fractional portion of LOCALTIMESTAMP is between 0.5 and 1.0 to see this.  If rounded values are acceptable for your use you're good to go.  If not you may need to use the last two version to convert the timestamp to a character string and back again.

Note also that the CHAR_TIMESTAMP value above still has the default number of fractional digits, but all are zero.  If you don't want this you'll need to use the TRUNCATED_TIMESTAMP value.

Share and enjoy.